# Mobile users are redirected to web view salesforce after login with mobile iOS SDK (8.3.0)

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, login, mobilesdk, ios, loginflow

We have faced with some intermittent behaviour on login process using mobile [SDK](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS) (8.3.0) on iPad devices - after login user is redirected to web version of salesforce (not custom mobile application). We cannot find exact steps to reproduce issue. Are there some configurations on SF side which can cause such behaviour or there are known issues?